# Help with getting answers to a question: how to improve?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

About one year ago I asked this question:

> [Deploy with capistrano through sftp (no ssh available)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979233/deploy-with-capistrano-through-sftp-no-ssh-available)

which has received 336 views so far, yet no answer at all.

What could I do to improve the odds of getting an answer? Do you suggest any improvement I could do to the question?

Thank you!

Comment: Add a bounty to the question. See [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for details.